# $\left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1337} = z$

Tags: complex-analysis

I want to solve:
$$\left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1337} = z$$

My attempt:

$$\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}=1e^{\frac\pi4i}$$
$$\implies \left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^{1337}=e^{\frac{1337}{4}i\pi}$$
$$=\cos\left(\frac{1337}{4}\pi\right)+i\sin\left(\frac{1337}{4}\pi\right)$$

Seems there is a better solution(if this is even correct). Can I have some advice please?

---

This is a past exam question for the record. It is very embarrassing I didn't get it.

Comment: Hint: $\left(\frac{i+1}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^2=i$

Comment: Note that $1336$ is divisible by $8$.

Comment: I see. so we get $-1$ for the first $8$,  and $1$ for the second. So divide by $8$, find out which $8$ I am on. (Even positive, odd negative) and then I can just go with what I started. This is odd, so negative

Comment: Simpler, $e^{1336 \pi i/4}=1$. because $e^{2\pi i}=1$.

Comment: @AndréNicolas That's what I meant, but I got my signs reversed. Thanks

Comment: @AndréNicolas Omgggg hahaha wow I missed the real meaning of divisible by $8$ until just now :P

Comment: Well, missing is good. Now the periodicity is engraved in the brain.

Answer (score 1):

HINT:

We have $1337\equiv=1\pmod8=8r+1$(say) where $r$ is a positive integer, in fact $=167$

$\implies\dfrac{1337}4=\dfrac{8r+1}4=2r+\dfrac14$

Answer (score 1):

Hint.
$$
\left(\frac{1+i}{\sqrt{2}}\right)^8=1.
$$

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is close to perfect. You only need to simplify the solution you have obtained.

$\cos(k+2n\pi) = \cos(k)$, so $\cos(\frac{1337}{4}\pi) = \cos(\frac{1}{4}\pi)$ and the same holds for $\sin(\frac{1337}{4}\pi)$.